# Laravel 5.1 Newsletter every month with cronjob

Tags: php, email, laravel, cron, mandrill

I want to be able to send an automated email to all my users with the top 5 projects of my application. I wanna do this with a cron job on my server.

I have constructed my function in my Marketing class. I created an artisan command but I just have no idea if my method will work. I have no idea how I can get the data in my variables to send in the mail.

#### I am not sure if my variable $name, $email, $projects will work in the mail and if the mail will actually be sent every month. I just don't think this code will work. And I don't have time to wait a month to test it out :p

My SendNewslettterCommand:

```
public function handle()
{
    foreach(User::all() as $user)
    {
        $name = $user->name;
        $email = $user->email;
        $projects = "a query to find top 5 projects of the week";
        $Marketing = new Marketing;
        $Marketing->sendNewsletter($name, $email, $projects);
    }
}
```

My sendNewsletter function in my Marketing class:

```
public function sendNewsletter($name, $email, $projects)
{
    // In template content you write your dynamic content if you use <mc:edit> tags.
    $template_content = [];
    $message = array(
        'subject' => 'SP*RK - TOP 5 projecten van de maand!',
        'from_email' => 'noreply@spark.com',
        'from_name' => 'SP*RK',
        'to' => array(
            array(
                'email' => $email,
                'name' => $name,
                'type' => 'to'
            )
        ),
        'merge_vars' => array(
            array(
                'rcpt' => $email,
                'vars' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NAME',
                        'content' => $name
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'PROJECTS',
                        'content' => $projects
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    MandrillMail::messages()->sendTemplate('newsletter', $template_content, $message);
}
```

If this is all correct my next steps would be to register my command in artisan by editing app/start/artisan.php and adding:

> Artisan::add(new SendNewsletterCommand);

After this I should my command to my crontab
Is this correct or not?

Comment: From your question, it's not clear what your problem is.
Your question is in the following format: **I have X, and I want to do Y. Is this correct or not?** To get better responses from users, try writing your question as follows: **I have X, when I do Y I expect Z1, but instead Z2 happens. Why is that?** 
Please write down what you have tried and where it went wrong.

Comment: to do your job task scheduler will be great http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling

Comment: wait one month to test it out? you really got something wrong there

Comment: I want the emails to be sent every month so I have to wait a month to see if it works or not?

Comment: You should go step by step here. First, define what attributes makes a project a top 5 project in your application. I'm sure someone can help you writing a query for that. Then, check if mandrill works. Run the command manually to test it. Scheduling your command should be your last concern, and you can either set a cronjob to run the command directly, or setup the Laravel scheduler. Imtiaz Pabel posted a link to the docs.

Comment: What do you mean "check if mandrill works"?